# Не работает сниппет в phpstorm. Решено

Tags: html, веб-программирование, phpstorm, sublime-text

Нашел сниппет для создания комментариев в html(и не только), в SB он работает на отлично. В phpstorm он разворачивается, но я не могу понять, почему переменные не подхватывает.

Пример сниппета для SB:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<!-- begin $1 -->
<div class="$1">
    $2
</div>
<!-- end $1 -->
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>di</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Пример сниппета для phpstorm:

```
<!-- Begin $1$ -->
<div class="$1$">

</div>
<!-- End $1$ -->
```

Всем спасибо, проблему решил путем полного сноса, и установки с нуля.

Comment: а название сниппета-то напишете?

Answer (score 1):

Что значит не подхватывает? При разворачивании сниппета появляется поле ввода на месте первого вхождения переменной (в красной рамке), при вводе значения код обновляется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ввод завершается по нажатию `Enter`.
Собственно сниппет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]